# SQL Count Distinct Group By

Tags: sql

I have data that looks like this:

| COLOR | SHAPE | ID1 | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Square | 11111111 | 11111111 |
| Red | Circle | 22222222 | 11111111 |
| Purple | Square | 33333333 | 22222222 |
| Purple | Square | 44444444 | 33333333 |
| Green | Circle | 55555555 | 33333333 |
| Green | Circle | 66666666 | 33333333 |
| Yellow | Square | 77777777 | 33333333 |
| Yellow | Square | 88888888 | 33333333 |
| Yellow | Circle | 99999999 | 33333333 |

and I want to return a query which gives every unique combination of color and shape along with the distinct count of each ID for each of those unique combinations. So the result should look like this:

| COLOR | SHAPE | Distinct_ID1 | Distinct_ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | Square | 1 | 1 |
| Red | Circle | 1 | 1 |
| Purple | Square | 2 | 2 |
| Green | Circle | 2 | 1 |
| Yellow | Square | 2 | 1 |
| Yellow | Circle | 1 | 1 |

I've tried quite a few different combinations of count(distinct) and group by, but none of them have worked.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Show us your query attempt, and we can guide you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty direct translation of your question:

```
select color, shape, count(distinct id1), count(distinct id2)
from t
group by color, shape;
```